# Is there a difference between Docker-Compose on Linux vs Windows?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, docker-network

I am running into a problem with deployment differences between Linux and Windows.  I have the following Docker-Compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  elasticsearch:

    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.0
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
      cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: "false"
    networks:
      logmetric:

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.0
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    networks:
      logmetric:
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    volumes:
      # Data persistency
      - influxdb_data:/var/lib/influxdb
    networks:
      logmetric:

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
    # Data persistency
    - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    networks:
      logmetric:

volumes:
  elasticsearch_data:
  influxdb_data:
  grafana_data:

networks:
  logmetric:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

When I do a `Docker-Compose -f compose_logging.yaml up` on **Windows** everything spins up normally and all the services are working.  **However,** if I transfer this yaml file over to my linux machine (CentOS 8) and do the same command, Kibana can't connect to the elastic search database.  I receive the errors:

> kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-03T21:41:42Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
>   kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-04-03T21:41:42Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}

If I 'curl http://localhost:9200' on the linux machine, which is the elasticsearch database, I get the response.  So I believe it is up and waiting for connections.  Response:

```
{
  "name" : "CQ7jdN0",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "swSAp0kUR7iQpqTpW3Iv_g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.3.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "424e937",
    "build_date" : "2018-06-11T23:38:03.357887Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.3.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

If I do an inspection on the docker network (`docker inspect andy_logmetric`) I get the following for the **LINUX** network:

```
[andy@Dev_Linux ~]$ docker inspect andy_logmetric
[
    {
        "Name": "andy_logmetric",
        "Id": "1d6544f05915e1673c5f541bcfe024fc3ad3d445cba43f0109a4bbd1e9faf9a0",
        "Created": "2020-04-03T15:59:24.036741117-04:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "091975207ec170c3c98223030add8f9b134f35b1aa05fd2016a31d985c73bc7f": {
                "Name": "andy_elasticsearch_1",
                "EndpointID": "b8263230459db25d873a79dff94e7d6b0a3cb8a2ed6bfff149559b54748e93cc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "10a22cc7ef65897417f58e0928598066ad899f25d43e2429c903282f5e74cef2": {
                "Name": "andy_kibana_1",
                "EndpointID": "1f8998efd1c61a40b9876ffd6502f0ec371ec926b5cd1e7851bd6dd31074c1c5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "542d6b764b084d99895f89c881aaf6fdf42edf63494edcd233dd35445706e3fc": {
                "Name": "andy_influxdb_1",
                "EndpointID": "4247f8fcb961e75fab6662133df9eb012a70707757db5ea6c37d7812c018f520",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e6fead6035cdb7b60e81114f124fa87084b7eb6b92c9b3800e66072dbcc82ba3": {
                "Name": "andy_grafana_1",
                "EndpointID": "9a0c892237fe891ef6e714bf8292857c9e2d68ac0f6abd7a99eba6daf6971f3c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "logmetric",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "andy",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.4"
        }
    }
]
```

I get the following for the **WINDOWS** network:

```
PS C:\Users\Michael> docker inspect docker-composefiles_logmetric
[
    {
        "Name": "docker-composefiles_logmetric",
        "Id": "d1bebbe4e73097fb6dcb4ab15750e2689e2e57da83e880b065063dcde055e576",
        "Created": "2020-04-03T21:24:14.531822721Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0820891e073e7e05cbcc7ab834cc599c640e6518bb36c848052b6a6c11b5c069": {
                "Name": "docker-composefiles_grafana_1",
                "EndpointID": "4e2c85709e89fd4b3bb609fc53eb4a4538b1fd93e51cfd73d8dc030d7707d6e3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8ada45e8a940102fe3145dee290af2da06d46d8bd465411da48bddf18d22167a": {
                "Name": "docker-composefiles_elasticsearch_1",
                "EndpointID": "5cc9b924eb46a7bc1bc07d3985779a1e0bf9ac4012c12333d6cbb96e3f78af2d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "902bec9dc51e542589a3da1f13648a3434bc2d10b6c5755adfa545d813032c18": {
                "Name": "docker-composefiles_influxdb_1",
                "EndpointID": "a0e5e49121616590260b04932b6943601f06dc3200564f9155ce2f2281625cf9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c054af26402fcbee5c9e727b8a3e8b009fd258734f060e1fc9dc19ade5f7f3fa": {
                "Name": "docker-composefiles_kibana_1",
                "EndpointID": "3f57dcaefde331cfa7bdc862f45a0dc95829cb89604b28347d8c452f0f60f396",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "logmetric",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker-composefiles",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.4"
        }
    }
]
```

Dumping those two files and running a compare yields nothing other than the obvious IDs and project names being different.

If I hit kibana with Chrome, on windows everything comes up as normal.  On the linux kibana it takes me to a disabled login screen that says you can't log in right now and to look at the logs.  (error message is above)

The network looks the same, yet Kibana can't reach the elastic search database on Linux, but can on Windows.

The docker versions on the linux machine are as follows:

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
[andy@Dev_Linux ~]$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
```

The docker versions on the windows machine are as follows:

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
PS C:\Users\Michael> docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
```

I don't know what else to look for.  Any thoughts as to what could be going on in the Linux environment?

Comment: depends_on doesn't actually depend on the database being ready. Could that be the problem? (that in a SO the database gets ready faster). Normally with a wait 30; this is solved.

Comment: @JorgeeFG I don't believe that is the problem.  The database is ready as far as I can tell.  To verify, I stopped the kibana container leaving the rest up, then after a few minutes I spun up the kibana container again (in the same docker network of course).  Unfortunately, the result was exactly the same.  So I don't think it's that the db isn't ready.  Plus, if I look at the compose, I don't get any Kibana messages until the db has finished writing and logs that it is ready.

Comment: Ran your docker-compose -f compose_logging.yaml up on my Fedora 30.  
curl -s localhost:5601/api/status | jq ".status.overall.state"
"green"

Comment: Ran your docker-compose -f compose_logging.yaml up on my Fedora 30.  
curl -s localhost:5601/api/status | jq ".status.overall.state"
"green"
docker-compose: 1.22
docker: 19.03.8
Should work for you. On linux, it ALWAYS works :-). Make sure you remove volumes when you "down" the stack (-v). Can this be content related? (.kibana index)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-prod-prerequisites

I remember having issues with elk on centos and the setting the kernel parameters on host helped.

Docker composes are just python scripts opearting on docker command itself, so the problem is not with it. More likely is the fact, that on windows you probably use docker-machine which is a linux hyper-v vm and on centos is just real linux, hence the difference.

You can also check `docker log [container name]` to see if elasticsearch doesn't print any warning on console.

Another check you can try is sh into containers using `docker exec -it /bin/sh` and ping the other container. Docker uses networks created within system so if in the network your centos server is in there's a subnet with same address as the one created by docker, host routing mechanism might send packets to the 'real' network rather than within the docker one.

Comment: This didn't solve the ultimate problem, but it was definitely a problem.  On one of the many many reboots I thought I got it nailed.  But on that reboot, I hit the problem you mentioned.  I set the VM memory size to resolve that, but sadly it didn't do anything for the kibana problem.   I gave you an upvote since it is a problem...but not the one I was after.

Comment: Any error logs on the container consoles of kibana and elasticsearch?

Comment: I updated my answer with yet another possibility you might have problem with.